# If Statement logic is not correct

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have this `if` statement and it is not working:

```
if (pEntry->GetStudentMaterialStudyPoint(StudentAssign::kBibleReading) == 1 &&
    (pEntry->GetStudentMaterialStudyPoint(StudentAssign::kItem1) == 1 && LOBYTE(LOWORD(pEntry->GetStudentAssignFlags()))) &&
    (pEntry->GetStudentMaterialStudyPoint(StudentAssign::kItem2) == 1 && HIBYTE(LOWORD(pEntry->GetStudentAssignFlags()))) &&
    (pEntry->GetStudentMaterialStudyPoint(StudentAssign::kItem3) == 1 && LOBYTE(HIWORD(pEntry->GetStudentAssignFlags()))) &&
    (pEntry->GetStudentMaterialStudyPoint(StudentAssign::kItem4) == 1 && HIBYTE(HIWORD(pEntry->GetStudentAssignFlags()))))
{
    MWBValidationErrorStruct errorMWBValidation;

    errorMWBValidation.iDateIndex = iDateIndex;
    errorMWBValidation.datMeeting = pEntry->GetMeetingDate();
    errorMWBValidation.eValidationErrorType = CChristianLifeMinistryDefines::MWBValidationErrorType::MaterialStudyPoints;

    m_listValidationErrors.push_back(errorMWBValidation);
}
```

}

I am trying to find out if all of the items have a value of 1. The first item (bible reading) will always be checked. But the items 1 to 4 only need to be checked if they are "included". That is what the `LOBYTE(LOWORD(pEntry->GetStudentAssignFlags()))` is for.

So,

```
Bible Reading - 1
Item 1 - 1
Item 2 - 1 - Not included
Item 3 - 1 - Not included
Item 4 - 1 - Not included
```

In the above scenario the `if` should be `true` because both BR and Item 1 are set to 1. We ignore the other 3 items.

```
Bible Reading - 1
Item 1 - 2
Item 2 - 3
Item 3 - 1 - Not included
Item 4 - 1 - Not included
```

In the above scenario the `if` should return `false` because all the values are not 1 and we are ignoring the last two items.

What is wrong with my `if` logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `(!included || x == 1)` to ignore checking an item if it's not included. Because of short circuiting, if `included` is false, you won't even check the other side of the OR, which is exactly what you want.

Your if could look like:

```
if (pEntry->GetStudentMaterialStudyPoint(StudentAssign::kBibleReading) == 1 &&
    (!LOBYTE(LOWORD(pEntry->GetStudentAssignFlags())) || pEntry->GetStudentMaterialStudyPoint(StudentAssign::kItem1) == 1) &&
    ...
```

This may be a little confusing, so let's make a truth table...

```
included | x | !included | x == 1 | (!included || x == 1)
------------------------------------------------------
 false   | 3 |   true    |  false |         true         
 true    | 3 |   false   |  false |         false       
 true    | 1 |   false   |  true  |         true
```

If `included = false`, then `!included` will be true, so `(!included || x == 1)` will always be true. This is what we want--if we're not included, just evaluate to true without even checking `x == 1`.

If `included = true`, then `!included` is false, so the value of `(!included || x == 1)` will be whatever `x == 1` is. Which is again what we want. If we're included, then depend on `x == 1`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `|| enabled`? Since `|| !enabled` would perform a check if **not** enabled.

Comment: But if I use `!` that means the inverse of the result. That would mean `if x == 1 || not included`. That is not right. With exception of the first item, all others should only be checked if they *are* included.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius it's an OR, so we short circuit if the first term is `true`. Basically we'll only end up checking if `x == 1` if `!enabled` evaluates `false` (it's enabled)

Comment: OK, but if `!enabled` is `true` and `x == 5`? Won't that trigger a invalid error?

Comment: @scohe001 Oh, right, in short-circuiting scenario it would work correctly. My apologies.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I drew you a truth table to try to make it a little clearer. This will evaluate `true` if `enabled` is `false` regardless of the value of `x`. But if `enabled` is `true`, it'll only be `true` if `x == 1`.

Comment: It works. I got to get my head around your truth table. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Happy to help! I tried to add a little explanation for the table. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: It is starting to make sense with this extra explanations. Thank you again.

Comment: @OznOg from the original question: "*But the items 1 to 4 only need to be checked if they are 'included'. That is what the `LOBYTE(LOWORD(pEntry->GetStudentAssignFlags()))` is for.*" I guess I wrote "enabled" instead of "included," my bad. I've updated the answer to better match the question. Good catch.